# AttributeError: 'Dash' object has no attribute 'run' in Python/Plotly-DASH

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dashboard

I am new in python and dashboard building so I am trying to print a phylogenetic tree with dash. But I encounter the following problem **AttributeError: 'Dash' object has no attribute 'run'**  as soon as I try to run the app. I know my code probably is problematic but this error in this case seems that dash is not capable to run applications.
`def main():
…#extracting the OG code of the corresponfing gene tree
return OG

def gene_tree(OG,search_path):
…“”“reads and prints a newick file with Phylo.read’”“”
return gene_tree

def species_tree():
…“”“reads and prints the species tree with Phylo.read”“”
return species_tree

```
app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(children = [
    html.H1(children="My APP",style={
        "textAlign": "center"
    }),
    html.Div(children="""
    Visualization of gene trees and orthogroups
    """),
    dcc.Graph(
        id= "species-tree",
        figure=species_tree())])
#@app.callback(Output = "id",
              ##Output = "children",
              #Output = "figure"
              #)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run.server(debug=True) #port=8050)
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be one method, `run_server`:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! Please consider marking this answer as accepted in that case.